# Errors while implementing datepicker jquery UI

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I have used datepicker in one of my page and when I hover over the respective div of date picker I am getting something like below

[image]

and also the below errors

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

```
 <div id="slider-main">
<div id="leftcolumn">
    <div id="slider">
    </div>
    <div id="slider-content">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rightcolumn">
    <div id="progress">
    </div>
    <div id="calender">
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone tell why these errors are coming?
Thanx in advance

Comment: Could you post some code, please?

Comment: seems like your css file not found some images

Comment: yes, give a while i will update

Comment: @leo I have given all the css files

Comment: @rjirji  so..where is your style.css?

Comment: @leo Where can I get it from. When I tried to download I could't find the file over internet

Comment: @rjirji  mybe  errors  not from jquery ui, check your style.css file

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [API manual](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) of jQuery-ui. At the bottom you will find an example with the linked CSS files. Try to do the same  as they did. Also make sure you downloaded all the correct files including the images, sprites, css files,...